# Problem in uploading url of current image to firestore database

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

When I upload FIRST image it gets store in Cloud Storage, but it doesn't store the image url in Firebase Firestore database, and when I upload the SECOND image it again get stores in cloud storage but in Firebase firestore database it stores the url of FIRST image and then again if I upload the THIRD image it gets store in cloud storage but it surprisingly upload the url of SECOND image in firebase firestore database and this goes so on. In short, it doesn't store the url of current image and on uploading the current image it uploads and display the previous one but if we check the cloud storage there are THREE images stored in it but in firestore database there are URL of only two images.I have tried both(update({"images": urls })) and (update({"images": FieldValue.arrayUnion(urls) })) as you can see I have commented the other one, both gives same result/problem. So, I don't know what is the reason for this? Pls help me out and thanks in advance. Here is the code below of uploading..

```
  _uploadImages() async {
   _images.forEach((image) {
  if(image!=null) {
    var _ref = _stoarge.ref().child("images/" + basename(image.path));
    _ref.putFile(image).whenComplete(() async {
      String url = await _ref.getDownloadURL();

      print(url);
      urls.add(url);
      print(url);
    });
  }
});
print("uploading:"+urls.asMap().toString());
await  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users")
  .doc(auth.currentUser.uid).update({"images": urls });
  //  .doc(auth.currentUser.uid).update({"images": FieldValue.arrayUnion(urls) });
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an `async/await` issue in your code. The `forEach` won't wait on `async` events inside and the `whenCompleted` is not awaited at all.

```dart
_uploadImages() async {
  for (var image in _images) {
    var _ref = _stoarge.ref().child("images/" + basename(image.path));
    await _ref.putFile(image);
    String url = await _ref.getDownloadURL();

    print(url);
    urls.add(url);
    print(url);
  }
  print("uploading:" + urls.asMap().toString());
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("users")
      .doc(auth.currentUser.uid)
      .update({"images": urls});
  //  .doc(auth.currentUser.uid).update({"images": FieldValue.arrayUnion(urls) });
}
```

Comment: List<File> _images = [ ];, still same issue. It uploaded in cloud storage but not in database.

Comment: What version of `firebase_storage` do you use?

Comment: firebase_storage: ^8.0.1

Comment: and. if use .add({"downloadURL":url}) then it shows red line under red and says "The method 'add' isn't defined for the type 'DocumentReference'. "

Comment: I have updated the answer. Can you pls try it again.